# How do we update data in multiple places via the Firebase console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I'm creating an Angular app with a Firebase backend. I've read about best practises with NoSQL databases and therefore know that data duplication is actually a GOOD thing. I've also read that they provide an "easy" way to update data that is in multiple places. However, this is via an API and not via the console.

Currently, I'm in the early stages and creating my data manually in the Firebase console. I didn't envisage creating a sort of admin area in the my app for me to update data. However, I'm now wondering about how I would update records which contain data that is stored in multiple places.

**What is the recommended way to achieve this?** Are we expected to be updating our data through our apps? The thing I like about the Firebase console is that I have GUI access to my data.

Answer (score 1):

Multi location updates (and transactions) can't be done from the console.  You'll have to write some code with the Firebase Admin SDK and manually run it in order to make that happen.

Comment: This seems like a big missing piece. I'd chosen Firebase because it's the best for young, small to medium projects. It's a backend as a service which meant I wouldn't have to build a server. Now it seems I'll need to do just that to input the data that the user will consume. The data isn't going to update very often. Am I perhaps missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Could not be accomplished through console. However to update a specific data point under a certain node through console, let's say key-value pair is "name":"John Doe" for node n1 and name under node n1 needs to be updated to "Mary Jane". It can be accomplished by adding the same key "name" under node n1 and corresponding value as "Mary Jane", then click Add button next to it. This will overwrite the previously added name "John Doe" i.e. name will be updated to "Mary Jane"